# SPListitem.SystemUpdate() and incremental crawl in FAST

Tags: 2010, search, crawling, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

Does FAST search incremental crawls ignore items that are updated via `SPListItem.SystemUpdate()`?

I am observing conflicting behaviors in multiple environments, so I am not sure what the exact behavior should be.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/2c01a3a5-4232-4287-9a14-6e39991bed50

And check if the vti_searchversion property is being updated when you call SPListItem.SystemUpdate(). If not, then it shouldn't be re-crawled as the modified date does not change when using SystemUpdate().